# Do two paths that merge into one have distinct derivatives at the "merge point"?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Let $p_1, p_2: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be two distinct continuous and differential paths that merge at point $t$.  That is $p_1(t_x) = p_2(t_x)$ for all $t_x \ge t$ and $p_1(t_0) \ne p_2(t_0)$ for all $t_0 < t$.

Does it necessarily follow that

$$
\frac{dp_1(t)}{dt} \ne \frac{dp_2(t)}{dt}
$$

or instead do we have equality

$$
\frac{dp_1(t)}{dt} = \frac{dp_2(t)}{dt}
$$

or is it indeterminate either way?

Comment: If they simply cross at a point, then of course they need not have the same derivative.  For example $p_1(t) = t$ and $p_2(t) = -t$ at $t=0$.  Just plot them.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Unless I'm missing something, crossing at a point isn't merging.  I'm interested in the case when one path merges into another path and stays identical past the initial point of intersection.

Comment: I believe taking the right-hand limit will prove their equality.

Comment: Are you assuming that the paths are $C^1$ (continuously differentiable), or just differentiable? Your notation is very awkward, as you're using $t$ both as a general variable and as a specific value of $t$.  Can you please make the notation and the question clearer?

Comment: $t\in \mathbb{R^1}$, yes?  and $\frac{dp_j}{dt}\in \mathbb{R^n}.$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $t<b$, then the derivative $p_1'(t)$ can be computed as the limit of $\frac{p_1(s)-p_1(t)}{s-t}$ as $s$ approaches $t$ from the right, and similarly for $p_2'(t)$.  Since $p_1(s)=p_2(s)$ for all $s\geq t$, these difference quotients are the same for $p_1$ and $p_2$, and so $p_1'(t)=p_2'(t)$.

Answer (score -1):

Indeterminate.

Here is one where they are equal:

Curve 1:  $x=t, y=t^2$, when $t<0,$ and $x=t,y=0, t\ge0.$

Curve 2:  $x=t, y=0, \forall t$

Here is a case where they are not equal:

Curve 1:  $x=t, y=t^2$, when $t<1,$ and $x=t,y=1, t\ge1.$

Curve 2:  $x=t, y=2-t^2$, when $t<1,$ and $x=t,y=1, t\ge1.$

Comment: How are the derivatives at $t=0$ not equal in the latter example?

Comment: @TedShifrin, You are right.  My example failed!  Will attempt a fix. ... Fixed it! (?)

Comment: Not differentiable at $t=1$?

Comment: Goes back to your question on the original question.  Do the paths need to be continously differentiable?  If so, then the left limit will equal the right limit.  If not, we can have non-differentiable as an allowable case.

Comment: Perhaps this is rather absurd because we could then make the merged path just about anything.  If we want smooth curves, then I guess they will turn out to be equal.